# flutter - row with elements of unequal weight

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a row that spans the width of the screen and with three buttons and a text that are equally spaced(flex = 1). I want the text to be aligned to the center of the screen and the buttons at the ends. is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> To cause a child to expand to fill the available space in the direction of this widget's main axis, wrap the child in an Expanded widget.

So you can try [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) and declare [Flex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html) in second `Expanded` widget.

**Solution**

```
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),color: Colors.red,child: Text("text 1"))),
              Expanded(flex: 3,child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),color: Colors.blue,child: Text("text 2"))),
              Expanded(child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),color: Colors.yellow,child: Text("text 3"))),
              Expanded(child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),color: Colors.green,child: Text("text 4"))),
            ],
          ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: And to change the alignment of the text inside the larger Expanded widget as shown in the question you could just wrap its child in an Align

Comment: @JonasZebari in this case even `textAlign: TextAlign.center` will work perfectly as Text's Container is wrapped by an Expanded widget.

Comment: Confirmed, should be marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hey check the code bellow I think it does what you want:

[image: button image]

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter buttons demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  List<int> values = [1, 2, 3];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Buttons demo'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Text('Button'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Some text',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  ),
                )),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Text('Button'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.purple,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Text('Button'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. The simplest I can think of is using a [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) widget.

In your example, you can use the `SizedBox` widget and add one additional box with the same dimensions as your left button on the left. The `SizedBox` will occupy the space but won't be rendered on screen.